# Android direct shared

Tags: java, android, share

I am trying to share a link from my app with direct share. The share dialog must be like the image below with the most used contacts from messaging apps, like WhatsApp contacts.

[image: Goal which I am trying to achieve]

This is the `Intent` structure which I am using for share the link:

```
 Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                        .from(getActivity())
                        .setType("text/plain")
                        .setText(sTitle+ "\n" + urlPost)
                        .getIntent();
                if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(
                        getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
```

And this is what my app shows:

[image: what my app shows]

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Um, if you are the one sharing the link, you do not implement a `ChooserTargetService`. WhatsApp, the contacts app, and other apps implement `ChooserTargetService`, if they wish.

Comment: Oh, maybe I am little confused about `ChooserTargetService`  but then, why the shared dialog from my app doesn't show contacts when I share a link like text?

Comment: Perhaps WhatsApp isn't implementing a `ChooserTargetService`, or they are not doing so for whatever `Intent` structure you are using for your request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `.createChooserIntent()` instead of `.getIntent()`

Answer (score 1):

Like this code below, you can use Intent.createChooser

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file://" + filePath);

            sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should use `.createChooserIntent()` instead of `.getIntent()`

Docs: This uses the [`ACTION_CHOOSER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER) intent, which shows

> an activity chooser, allowing the user to pick what they want to before proceeding. This can be used as an alternative to the standard activity picker that is displayed by the system when you try to start an activity with multiple possible matches, with these differences in behavior:
>
> - You can specify the title that will appear in the activity chooser.
> - The user does not have the option to make one of the matching activities a preferred activity, and all possible activities will
>     always be shown even if one of them is currently marked as the
>     preferred activity.
>
> This action should be used when the user will naturally expect to
>   select an activity in order to proceed. An example if when not to use
>   it is when the user clicks on a "mailto:" link. They would naturally
>   expect to go directly to their mail app, so startActivity() should be
>   called directly: it will either launch the current preferred app, or
>   put up a dialog allowing the user to pick an app to use and optionally
>   marking that as preferred.
>
> In contrast, if the user is selecting a menu item to send a picture
>   they are viewing to someone else, there are many different things they
>   may want to do at this point: send it through e-mail, upload it to a
>   web service, etc. In this case the CHOOSER action should be used, to
>   always present to the user a list of the things they can do, with a
>   nice title given by the caller such as "Send this photo with:".